Получение нескольких массивов через JSON
Не могу решить проблему получения AJAX данных со стороны сервера. Суть такая -
идет запрос в БД. Через  fetch открываю ('data.php');
В data.php выборка строк из БД такого плана :
...
$row = $result->fetch_assoc() 
echo json_encode($row) 
...

на стороне JS вывожу строки через JSON
let r = await response.json())

r.name работает только если доступна одна строка, например name = 'Lisa' в БД;
Если есть name = 'Lisa', name= 'Albert' и т.д. дает ошибку синтаксиса JSON - в консоле пишет что нарушен синтаксис JSON.
Смотрю на странице data.php через print_r всё правильно. Получается два массива [... name='Lisa'...], [..name='Ablert'...]
но такие данные не получается парсить в JSON как я понял
то есть, когда выборка для одной строки [... name='Lisa'...] всё четко, а если больше, то не выходит передать в JSON
как получить много строк выборки на сторону JS, чтобы их выводить в виде массива с ключами

"Получается два массива [... name='Lisa'...], [..name='Ablert'...] но такие данные не получается парсить в JSON как я понял". Значит, наверное нужно сделать ОДИН массив, в котором будет два элемента?

Почитайте про формат JSON - как выглядит, какие требования... 2 массива это не json

нашел решение тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51172387/json-parse-unexpected-non-whitespace-character-after-json-data-at-line-1-column
массив нужно сделать в качестве значения ключа другого массива.
$mass1 = ['name'=>'string'];
$mass2 = ['name'=>'string'];
$arr[] = $mass1;
$arr[] = $mass2;
$superMass = ['super'=>$arr];
echo json_encode($superMass);

У вас, вероятнее, проблема в том что вы выводите каждый $row через echo отдельно от других, и в результате такого вывода не формируется корректный JSON. Ваше решение корректно, но можно добавлять все результаты в массив, и потом его echo jsoнить в конце ( echo json_encode($arr) ), без 'super'.
